# curl: POST and cookie issue

Tags: curl, cookies

I'm using curl to download some weather data from a webpage that requires a form to be filled with the fields username, password and action. The following command is working fine and I'm able to login successfully. The cookies are saved in "cookie.txt"

```
curl -c cookie.txt -d "username=###" -d "password=####" -d "action=login" https://####/includes/forms/form_action.php
```

Next, I first used the developer tool in Mozilla Firefox to discover which command I must send to get the data:

```
curl 'https://####/includes/weather_graph.php' -H 'Host: forecast.prewind.eu' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0' -H 'Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://####/includes/weather.php' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=st3prmqrvl5jl0qkobo3h68191' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'parkID=###&promoterID=###&pDate=###'
```

It works just fine, but as you can see the Cookie is not the one I desire once I'll be downloading this data daily. Then I changed the command to include -b cookie.txt in order to use the latest cookie I've got.

```
curl -b cookie.txt 'https://####/includes/weather_graph.php' -H 'Host: forecast.prewind.eu' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0' -H 'Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://####/includes/weather.php' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'parkID=###&promoterID=###&pDate=###'
```

Oddly, this new command doesn't work, the server doesn't respond anything and I've no idea what to do to fix it. The headers and the post parameters are the very same, the only information that changed is the cookie.

Comment: Usually, you can do "curl -c cookies URL2" on the page with the form first, then you submit the query in a second invoke and there you use the cookies from the previous with "curl -b cookies -d blablabla URL2"...

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your comment. It's exactly the "curl -b cookies -d blablabla URL2" that is not working. It only works when I use the curl command copied from firefox developer console. I wonder why...

Comment: add -v to see what's happening  with your request (-v for verbose)

Comment: @nafas , I use -v in the code, it displays '200 OK' for the first example and  '500 Internal Server Error' for the second

Comment: The only different line from the commands is:
`< Content-Encoding: gzip` , the one that fails does not show this in the header response

Comment: It's working now. The problem was a script called "start.php" that runs after the authentication. I have no ideia what it does (curl sends a GET) but it seems this script provides access to the others scripts (weather.php and weather_graph.php).